# Getting nearby places to the device current location using google places api on javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places

I'm using Google maps API and Google Places API to get the user's device current location and to retrieve the nearby restaurants, gyms, etc. from that location. I've checked the official google documentation and I've created this code:

html code:

```
<div id="map">  </div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=I_REPLACED_MY_KEY_IN_HERE&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer ></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
var pos;
var request;
var place;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  getLocation();
  getNearByPlaces();
  callback();
}

  function getLocation(){
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

function getNearByPlaces(){
   request = {
    location: pos,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status){
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
    for (var i =0; i<results.length; i++){
      place = results[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the map with the nearby places and the device current location, the problem is that I'm not getting only the restaurants as I specified in my request, I want to get restaurants only in 500 radius and to retrieve their latitudes and longitudes, getnearbyplaces and callback aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geolocation service is asynchronous.  You need to call `getNearByPlaces` when the location is available, in the callback function for the geolocation service.

```
function getLocation() {
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      getNearByPlaces(pos); // depends on value of pos
   // existing error handling...
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2adLwbuf/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
var pos;
var request;
var place;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 6
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  getLocation();
  // getNearByPlaces();
  // callback();
}

function getLocation() {
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      console.log("getLocation:" + pos.lat + "," + pos.lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
      })
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      map.setCenter(pos);
      getNearByPlaces(pos);
    }, function() {
      console.log("calling handleLocationError(true)");
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    console.log("calling handleLocationError(false)")
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

function getNearByPlaces(pos) {
  console.log("getNearByPlaces:" + pos.lat + "," + pos.lng);
  request = {
    location: pos,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log("callback received " + results.length + " results");
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i]));
      place = results[i];
      var mark = createMarker(results[i]);
      bounds.extend(mark.getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  } else console.log("callback.status=" + status);
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}
```

```css
  html,
  body,
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```